# Help with binary division problem dividing $1001011010000$ by $1001$

Tags: arithmetic, binary, binary-operations

I have this binary division practice problem, I am not sure how to deal with a leading 1 when pulling down the next bit.
Here is my process, I'll try to make it clear to where my confusion comes about, I'm not quite sure on how to format the long division symbol here, so please pretend that $1001)....$ is in front of all the bits below and accept my apologies.

I also use the code block as it wasn't clear within a latex block imho.

```
 1001011010000
-1001
    00       //remainder 0 bring down next bit
    001      //smaller than 1001 bring down next bit
    0011     // still smaller bring down next bit
      110    //still smaller bring down next bit
      1101   //bigger subtract/XOR 1001 
     -1001 
       1000  //bring down next bit, here starts my confusion!
```

should do this next?:

```
 10000
-01001
```

if yes, do I ignore the leading 1? Or how do I proceed, I can't find an example in the textbook we use or elsewhere online and I've looked for a few days.

it's the only example where this occurs but I'm guessing all the other ones were picked to be nicely solvable.

thank you for looking at this for me and helping me understand on how to proceed now.

Comment: Where does the rightmost `1` in the line annotated "bigger subtract/XOR 1001" come from? You should have pulled the next bit from the dividend which is `0`.

Comment: @Troposphere I'm sorry this is a typo, that should be a  `1`, I copied the original bit string wrong. 
If it were a `0` I know how to deal with it. 
It's really about what to do when I have 1000 and subtract 1001?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the next step, subtract `1001` from `10000`, yielding `0111`.

You don't just ignore the leading `1` in `10000` -- you need it to borrow from, or the subtraction would be impossible!

Note that just in base ten or any other base, you need to *subtract* the (multiple of) the divisor from the remainder-so-far. That may require keeping track of borrows. Subtraction is not the same thing as binary XOR even though *for some inputs* it gives the same results.

Comment: Hi Troposphere, thank you for this explanation, in the textbook as well as in lecture script we were told that in the case for polynomial division for CRC checks we ignore borrows and even in the textbook (Computer Networking, Kurose) it says so, along with equating subtraction with XOR. I am very confused now. Is that different from normal binary division?

Comment: @oliver: Yes, _polynomial division_ is a different beast than division of _numbers_. When you use bit patterns to represent plain old integers, additional and subtraction needs carries/borrows just in base ten, and that is still the case for the intermediate additions/subtractions during long multiplication and division division.

Comment: In CRC (and also some more advanced error correction schemes) you take the same bit patterns to represent _polynomials_ over $\mathbb F_2$, one bit for each coefficient. In the polynomial setting, "addition" and "subtraction" both become XOR (that is, _without_ carries), and this is then what you must use when multiplying/dividing _polynomials_.

Comment: Since you didn't mention otherwise in your question, I assumed you were dividing _numbers_. If you're instead dividing _polynomials_, you would do subtraction one step earlier -- when you reach `1000` you can clear the high bit by subtracting `1001` _as polynomials_, yielding `0001`.

Comment: thank you very much, so in very plain terms, I always ignore the integer value of the bitstring but instead just see it as subtracting one monomial from another? I.e. just the coefficients?
Say if I had 1000 - 1111 instead I'd get 0111? I'm sorry for the confusion

Comment: @oliver: Correct, when you're working with polynomials over $\mathbb F_2$.